# Passing an object as parameter to a method (Java)

Tags: java, class, object, methods, javac

[Main File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFDTe.png)

[My class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLHD5.png)

The problem I am encountering is that when I attempt to compile all my program it tells me it cant find all the variables in line 17 of my main file.

I must pass the object to the `printmovieinfo` method.

Comment: please don't provide images for further questions , only provide the code in question

Comment: Small code samples like this can be posted as part of the question.  Please do _not_ post your code as links to .png files.  One of StackOverflow's purposes is to maintain a question and answer database that can be used for a long time in the future, and posting links to temporary URL's defeats that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Your `printMovie` method takes a `Movie` parameter named `citizenkane` (which is a bad name, since the method should be usable on any movie, not just that one).  To get the title and other information, you'll need to tell the program that it will be getting the information from `citizenkane`.  It won't read your mind.

The problem is that in the `Movie` class, you've provided methods for setting up that information, but no methods for getting the information out.  In addition to `set` methods, you'll need `get` methods to get the information, like:

```
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
```

Then, if you have a movie object named `m`, you can use `m.getTitle()` to get the title.  `m.title` won't work because the `title` field in the `Movie` is `private`, meaning it isn't visible to any other classes.  Use this syntax with your `citizenkane` parameter to retrieve the title and other information.

Answer (score 0):

use the reference `citizenkane` in `printMovieInfo()`, but notice that all the variables in your class `Movie` are `private` so you can't access them in `printMovieInfo()`. so either make them `public` or provide public getters for them and use them in `printMovieInfo()`

Comment: Ummm, aren't those `private` fields?

Answer (score 0):

Write 'get' methods in your Movie class. These are just simple functions that return your private variables. Then access them in your main class with citizenkane.getTitle(), and so on.